# While testing Air for iPhone app, iOS Simulator asks for IP or Hostname

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, air, simulator

I'm working on an update to my iPhone app. It is made with Air, I'm compiling with Flash CS6 or CC.

I want to use the possibilty to test my app directly in the iOS Simulator.

It works as far, as the app shows on the Home Screen of my Simulator Phone. But when I start the app, the iOS Simulator asks for an IP or Hostname.

I tried my local IP, as my global. In this case, nothing happens, and 15 seconds later, iOS Simulator asks again.

If I cancel the request, the app will be stuck in the splash screen.

What IP is asked for?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's most likely looking to connect to the debugger (on your local machine). Are you debugging or just running the app?

Comment: I would like to simply run it.

Comment: My question was how are you launching the app? I normally use Flash Builder, but both that and Flash Pro let you launch your apps by either "running" them or "debugging" them. The latter will hold execution of your app until it connects to the debugger in Flash Builder/Flash Pro.

Comment: @nbuechi, Sunil D.'s advice here is accurate. It's asking because you're running in debug mode so it wants to connect to your computer so it can send over debugging nfo.